# Reason behind close vote got changed

Tags: support

I voted to close a [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56942/alabamas-legendary-lizards-what-species-are-they) being too-broad (as far as I remember) but the close reason got changed. The system now states that the close reason is that the question was 'unclear'.

[image]

From [help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) I found a special ability of the moderators:

> Moderators can perform large-scale maintenance actions such as **merging** questions and tags, tag synonym approvals, and **so forth**.

So was this merging a part of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The close reason displayed is the one selected by the majority of voters.

Comment: I would have assumed that to be true but when questions are VTC as off-topic the ones agreeing to a common off-topic reason are usually mentioned together(as in this [question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56919/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-molecular-basis-of-disease)). But here when users are voting with different reasons (I presume) merging them into one without mentioning that there were a bunch of people who agreed upon one common reason seems a bit unlikely. That's why I think it wasn't done by the system but the moderators.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Canadianer is correct; only the most common reason is shown. In your example, the off-topic reason must have been the most common reason to close (maybe others voted unclear, too broad etc). However, there has been many suggestions at SE-Meta that all close-reasons should be shown, see eg http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @fileunderwater I was the last one to VTC the [question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/56919/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-molecular-basis-of-disease) and as far as I remember the rest of the votes were cast with the reason off-topic, but with varying  sub-reasons. Thank you for the links, the matter has been discussed over and over again in meta and they haven't executed the feature yet. But it is really annoying to find my name associated with something that I didn't choose.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh I agree that SE should implement this, since it is rather misleading to show a close reason together with a series of user names, when the users might have voted for completely different close reasons. Showing all reason would also provide useful feedback to the OP for revisions. Otherwise they might fix one problem, but the other ones might remain.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh I checked the history for this post, and it got two "too broad" and three "unclear what you are asking" votes. This has nothing to do with me casting the last vote, it goes by the majority of the votes cast.

Comment: @Chris I realized it later, I didn't recall correctly.